# How To Refresh Checkout Page After Adding Order Bump (WooCommerce / WooFunnels)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

**Update #1:** I've managed to get the page to refresh on click, but due to the delay in adding the additional product to the cart the billing fields aren't shown until a second refresh is done. **So, simply refreshing the page on click is not a good solution.**

Now, I'm thinking loading the whole checkout page via ajax might be a solution?

I'm not sure how to do this (or if it's even the best idea), so if anyone has a way to implement this or a better solution feel free to share.

**Update #2:** Here is a loom video that shows the problem in real time.
https://www.loom.com/share/8e49e8663f1c4599a306c9c9948636b2

When my mouse goes off-screen at 0:15 I'm refreshing the page.

---- Original Post ----

My checkout page is not adding the proper billing fields after an order bump is applied to the cart (via the checkbox to add an additional product to the order). This is causing customers to be charged but no order is generated on my side. This is because the cart refreshes via ajax, while the rest of the checkout page does not.

To replicate the error, add a free product to your cart from this page:
https://blacklotusaudio.com/free-downloads/

Then, skip the popup offer and head to checkout and click to add the additional product to your order via the order bump checkbox. You'll notice the billing fields stay the same unless you refresh the page, which is what I believe is causing the issue here.

So, my solution is to refresh the page every time the order bump is clicked, I'm just not 100% certain how best to do it.

I've tried adding a modified version of this code to the page, but I cannot correctly identify the right element(s) to target as there is no "button" on the order bump to select.

```
<button type="button" onClick="refreshPage()">Close</button>

<script>
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
} 
</script>
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be much appreciated. I'm sure there is a better way of solving this problem than refreshing the page, but right now that's the best I can come up with.

**Edit - Here's what I'm using to make the free downloads work:**

```
function sv_free_checkout_fields() {

    // first, bail if WC isn't active since we're hooked into a general WP hook
    if ( ! function_exists( 'WC' ) ) {
        return; 
    }

    // bail if the cart needs payment, we don't want to do anything
    if ( WC()->cart && WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) {
        return;
    }

    // now continue only if we're at checkout
    // is_checkout() was broken as of WC 3.2 in ajax context, double-check for is_ajax
    // I would check WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT but testing shows it's not set reliably
    if ( function_exists( 'is_checkout' ) && ( is_checkout() || is_ajax() ) ) {
                
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'woo_custom_order_button_text' ); 

function woo_custom_order_button_text() {
    return __( 'SEND MY DOWNLOADS', 'woocommerce' ); 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'misha_email_first' );
 
function misha_email_first( $checkout_fields ) {
    $checkout_fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 4;
    return $checkout_fields;
}
        
add_filter('woocommerce_mailchimp_woocommerce_newsletter_default_checked', function ($checked) {
    return true;
});

        // remove coupon forms since why would you want a coupon for a free cart??
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );

        // Remove the "Additional Info" order notes
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );

        // Unset the fields we don't want in a free checkout
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', function( $fields ) {

            // add or remove billing fields you do not want
            // fields: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2
            $billing_keys = array(
                'billing_last_name',
                'billing_company',
                'billing_phone',
                'billing_address_1',
                'billing_address_2',
                'billing_city',
                'billing_postcode',
                'billing_country',
                'billing_state',
            );

            // unset each of those unwanted fields
            foreach( $billing_keys as $key ) {
                unset( $fields['billing'][ $key ] );
            }

            return $fields;
        } );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp', 'sv_free_checkout_fields' );
```

Comment: What do you mean by order bump? That checkbox that adds an additional product?

Comment: That's correct. I'll update the original post so to make that more clear.

Comment: Ah I see the billing info is supposed to update when you do the bump? What new fields are supposed to be there?

Comment: I'm running a script that hides them from the free orders as they're just not needed, but the fields that *should* be there are last name, and the billing address fields (address, city, zip, etc.). Because of this script the fields are still hidden until the page is refreshed, so if you add the additional product to your cart and refresh the page you'll see all the fields that are required for a purchase. (Edit: added details to comment)

Comment: Ahh - so the free products are not being treated as physical - not needing address until a physical product is being added. Have you tried adjusting the woocommerce settings > accounts & privacy. Maybe enforcing an account to be created can fix this problem for you or something similar?

Comment: If you are hiding the fields yourself can you share that script? Are you using jQuery / javascript?

Comment: I've added the code I'm using to hide the fields to my initial post. Because I don't want to collect billing info for a free download, the best solution I can come up with is to refresh the page every time the additional product is added so the billing fields show up.